# Robot Framework: Cannot load Profile on Firefox Browser

Tags: python, firefox, robotframework

I test firefox browser using

Robot Framework 3.0.1
Selenium2
Firefox 61
gecko 0.21

but i get following error message.

```
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. 
Profile Dir: c:\users\pewong\appdata\local\temp\tmph5c70q\webdriver-py-profilecopy 
If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Please help. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource          ../Resources/Generic/common_resource.txt
Resource          ../Resources/Generic/generic_variable.txt

*** Test Cases ***
PhpTravels_Net
    : FOR    ${browser}    IN    @{listBrowser}
    \    Open Browser    https://planet2.swift.com/Pages/default.aspx    ${browser}
    \    Log    ${browser}
    ${search}=    Generate Random String    12    [LETTERS]
    Close All Browsers
```

Comment: what code trial you tried?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install -U selenium`